# How to add to Aurelia CLI's list of watched directories

Tags: aurelia

All of my program code is in the `src/` directory of my project as per usual, but I have a number of json data files in a sibling folder to `src/` called `data/`.  I'd like it if BrowserSync would automatically refresh the page after detecting changes to my json files in `data/` as it does to html/css/ts in `src/`, but I'm not sure where (or how) in `aurelia.json` I'd add that directory in to be watched (even though nothing in there needs to be processed or transpiled).

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out, was looking in the wrong place.  I appended a line to the `watch` function in `aurelia_project/tasks/run.ts` to look like:

```
let watch = function() {
  gulp.watch(project.transpiler.source, refresh).on('change', onChange);
  gulp.watch(project.markupProcessor.source, refresh).on('change', onChange);
  gulp.watch(project.cssProcessor.source, refresh).on('change', onChange);
  gulp.watch("data/**/*.json", refresh).on('change', onChange);                  <=====
};
```

and that did the trick.

Comment: I'd recommend putting that directory in your aurelia.json file and referencing it like the other ones. It's just a JSON file, so you can add your own props to the project as you wish.

Comment: So adding something like `data: {source: "data/**/*.json"}` to aurelia.json and then referencing it in run.ts as `project.data.source`?

Comment: Yep. That's all you need to do